# Creating multiple Custom List in Suite CRM

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I created a custom modules which contains some fields relevant to business and status field. I need 5 list views created in this module based on the value present in status column. Eg. View for cases with status as

1. Pending
2. Sent for approval
3. Approved
4. Rejected

Currently one option that i found to achieve this by creating multiple modules for multiple list view but the challenge here is that the template file used for uploading cases contains more that 100000 records in it and adding multiple module for each view might increase the upload time drastically.

Can someone help me on this.

Comment: You can customize the list view tpl file and use different tpl files accordingly. In view.list.php, use conditions and render different tpl files.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom buttons for that status. And when you click on that buttons you can override the list view query according to that button.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30263803)